# Custom Cursor too small in wpf application

Tags: wpf, windows

I'm trying to use a custom cursor in order to use for drag and drop (in my application, the adorner method has significant lag behind the cursor)

Everything is working well using https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/17/713-setting-the-cursor-to-an-image-of-an-uielement-while-dragging/ but, when I display my cursor, it's much smaller than my original.

How do I adjust the cursor size in order to allow the cursor to be a similar size to the element I'm copying?

Comment: Is the icon the correct size? What size is it?

Comment: It seems smaller than the usual one, its definitely smaller than the height/width of the underlying bitmap coming from the Element.